# Would the cost of an item be more accurately expressed as a ratio of cost vs. minimum wage?

Tags: cost-basis, spending

I'd like to express the cost of items in a document that can help with spending decisions in the long term.
For instance, an item costs $30, with the minimum wage being $15/hr. in the present year.

If I express the cost of the item as a ratio of the minimum wage,
i.e.: 30 / 15 = 2,
it would indicate one would have to work for 2 hours at a minimum wage to obtain the item at the present time.

Would it then be reasonable to use this information and compare it at a future time, where if one has to work less time at minimum wage to obtain the same item, then the cost of the item has actually decreased, even if the item's dollar value had increased?

Comment: This adds an unnecessary layer of complexity for everyday budgeting.

Comment: This could be anywhere from useful to useless depending on your clients. Do most of them actually work minimum wage? If your clients are earning many times minimum wage they wont care what it is.

Comment: You should use "your" actual income, not minimum wage.

Comment: @Vality Note that this is not for any client, but just for interest/curiosity purposes. I'm trying to think of a universal benchmark of value to determine if its still worth it to pay for the same products and services in the future in the event of price increases.

Comment: @RonJohn Since anyone's income (assuming they are working) can be >= minimum legal wage, then wouldn't it be reasonable to just use the minimum wage as a benchmark when judging whether or not the cost of goods and services are too high? For instance, where I live, I see the price of eggs increase compared to 10 years ago due to inflation, but it has actually decreased as percentage of the minimum wage now compared to 10 years ago, so they have actually become more affordable in terms of the time traded at work to obtain the same item.

Comment: If your income is now $30/hour while the minimum wage has remained fixed, why do you care about the cost of eggs relative to the MW?  (Although, **if you were an economist** the cost of eggs relative to the MW might be highly relevant.)

Comment: @RonJohn I'm making an assumption that people/market would demand wages /prices with the minimum wage as a benchmark; i.e.: an economist would demand higher wages then a store cashier; if the wage of a store cashier goes up, then so too would an economist's in proportion to the cashier's, eventually. I don't know if such an assumption is reasonable (this is probably what I'm trying to ask). "Eggs" was an example, but the same idea in evaluating the cost of goods would apply to tax payments, rent, cars, entertainment, etc.

Comment: The economist would care **because he's writing a paper** demonstrating how costs have risen (or fallen) for various groups of people.

Comment: @RonJohn **Note: I have no economics background, am not an economist, nor am  writing a paper.** I ask this question because a lot of people seem to consider just the monetary cost of goods making financial decisions, while I've always intuitively thought about it in terms of the time exchanged to obtain that good.

Comment: You're completely missing the point.

Comment: @RonJohn Okay, I see your point, thanks, some of my questions/answers are more relevant in the Economics Stack Exchange.

Comment: You might find the concept of "purchasing power parity" and The Economist magazine's "Big Mac Index" of interest.

Comment: The minimum wage is set by a political process not an economic process, there's no reason why it should be an accurate basis to express the cost of goods, or compare the costs of a good across time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimum wage? No. Your actual wage? Perhaps.

What you seem to seek is the idea that “time is money” and that some of us instinctively think about how much time we would work to buy an item, or pay for a service. For example, the big TV, say it’s $1000. That money is 138 hours to a minimum wage worker, but only 40 hours to those making $50,000, etc.

The process isn’t so much accurate as it might help you decide on large purchases.

Comment: Okay, I can extend that idea to help with future financial management and determine where costs of goods or services are rising the most relative to actual wage at the time.

Comment: @plu it's particularly good with young people when getting their first allowance or first job.

Comment: In this case, is it better written "money is time", as in "time worked"?

Comment: @RonJohn exactly, hours one needs to work to buy an item.

Comment: Though the utility of looking at prices this way does decrease when you reach a point where a significant fraction of your income isn't coming from an hourly wage :-)

Comment: James, absolutely. After retiring, my own thoughts on expenses changed to that of sticking to a budget. The question itself can use some editing to tighten its scope, and to address RonJohn’s also excellent points. As written, it’s running the risk of closure as “too broad” or “unclear”. The concept itself, “expenses/purchases as converted to hours worked by the individual” has some merit and some application.

Answer (score 1):

It only makes sense to think of the cost of an item as the amount of time at minimum wage it would take to purchase the item if your marginal rate is the same as the minimum wage.  If you make more than the minimum wage now or expect to make more than the minimum wage in the future, you should base your numbers on that instead.

The minimum wage is rather disjunct from the amount of time it would take to earn an item.  For example, the minimum wage at the federal level of the US was $5.15 for ten years.  Yet for most people, wages increased during that span of time.

If you live someplace where the minimum wage is indexed to inflation, you might be better off just using the CPI for this purpose.  Although again, that leaves off any increase that you might get from experience, etc.